# CSS border not bind

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the following menu bar

[image]

And the truth is that my result is as follows:

[image]

My main problem is I do not know how to make the side edge reaches the top of the layer, the CSS and HTML code I am using is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
 <nav>
    <ul class="actions">
      <li class="header_nav">
         <a href="#">Iniciar Sesi&oacute;n</a>
      </li>
     <li class="header_nav notifications">
       <a href="#"></a>
     </li>
    <li class="header_nav like">
       <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="header_nav history">
       <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.actions a:before{ 
content: "";
float: left;
width: 20px;
height: 19px;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
background: url(../img/menu.png);
}

.history a:hover:before,
.history a:focus:before,
.history a:active:before {
    background-position: 40px -22px;
    }

.history a:before { background-position: 40px 0; }

.notifications a:hover:before,
.notifications a:focus:before,
.notifications a:active:before {
    background-position: 0 -22px;
    }

.notifications a:before { background-position: 0 0; }

.like a:hover:before,
.like a:focus:before,
.like a:active:before {
    background-position: 20px -22px;
    }

.like a:before { background-position: 20px 0; }

#header{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

nav{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

nav li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

li{
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

thanks for everything!

Comment: Can you please pose a link to that page?

Comment: I didn't understand the problem very well. You want your menu bar to stick in page edges and now has little space?

Comment: I've uploaded this url but now I do not know for what reason I do not show icons ... http://voragile.com/pisos/

Comment: Ramon, it's awesome that you were willing to upload your code to that page when asked, but unless you are willing to keep that test page up *forever*, a better way to do it in the future is to use a JSFiddle. Then people can play around with your code and update it themselves to give you examples, and you'll never have to worry about hosting the test page. Glad you and Alek were able to figure it out though, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes:

```
nav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
height: 42x; // for 1px difference to the bottom
}
```

And this if you don't want so empty space to the left:

```
.row {
margin-left: -60px;
margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Comment: The text sticks well to the bottom line but the logos seems to lack a pixel to touch the bottom edge.

Comment: You have to add custom height.

Comment: Did this change fix your problem?